# WP didn't show post in right category

Tags: wordpress

I have made a wp theme. But i have some problems. When i click in a category, it shows all of my posts, not the posts in that category. And when i find a keyword, if it has the results, it shows all of my posts, not the posts match with the keyword. I don't know what happened. :(
Please help me, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a category.php template file? See [Category Templates « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)

> And when i find a keyword, if it has the results, it shows all of my
>   posts, not the posts match with the keyword.

That's a completely different problem. Do you mean search?